# Cómo acceder a la variable request en Vistas Basadas en Clases

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models

Estoy tratando de habilitar las [Páginas Aceleradas para Móviles](https://www.ampproject.org/es/) o **AMP** en mi blog personal, pero quiero eliminar la lógica de las plantillas y elegir desde la misma vista, las plantillas que usará el blog, dependiendo si se solicita la versión de escritorio o la AMP.

Hice un intermediario o *middleware* que detecta cuando se solicita una página AMP y actualiza una variable que coloca en el `request`. Una vez ahí, la uso para activar en las diferentes secciones en las plantillas,

```
<h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline">
  {{ article.title }} {% if es_amp %}(versión AMP){% endif %}
</h1>
```

que convenientemente se convierte en:

```
<!-- URL: http://localhost:8000/trinos/especializacion/amp/ -->
<h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline">Especialización (versión AMP)</h1>
```

pero esto ocupa **mucha lógica en las plantillas** ya que aparece en muchas partes, y es algo que deseo evitar.

Lo que quiero hacer es desde la vista seleccionar la plantilla que debe usar cada solicitud.

En el contexto tengo una variable que indica si la solicitud `es_amp`:

```
# settings.TEMPLATES.OPTIONS.context_processors.apps.blog.context.variables
def variables(request):
    return {
        # ...
        'base_template': 'base_amp' if request.es_amp else 'base',
        'es_amp': request.es_amp,
        # ...
    }
```

#### Primer intento

Y quiero usar esta variable en mi CBV así:

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView, CacheMixin):
    cache_timeout = CACHE_TTL
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'article'
    template_name = '%s/entry_detail.html' % self.request.base_template
```

Aquí, como es obvio, obtenido el error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

#### Segundo intento

También lo intenté así:

```
from apps.blog.context import variables

class EntryDetail(DetailView, CacheMixin):
    # bla bla bla
    template_name = '%s/entry_detail.html' % variables('base_template')
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
File "/Volumes/datos/Proyectos/nspaces/src/apps/blog/context.py", line 15, in variables
    'base_template': 'base_amp' if request.es_amp else 'base',
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'es_amp'
```

#### Tercer intento

Ahora intento la solución que [propone Juan M. Hidalgo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91698/638) y obtengo el error: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'base_template'`. Porque `WSGIRequest` contiene esto:

```
request: <WSGIRequest: GET '/trinos/especializacion/amp/'>
```

Luego intenté moviendo mi *middleware* al principio de la lista, pero el resultado fue el mismo.

#### ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la variable `request` en una Vista Basada en Clases?

> #### Nota
>
> Por alguna razón, esta línea nunca funcionó y no estaba en el `request`: `'base_template': 'base_amp' if request.es_amp else 'base',`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución sería usar [get_template_names()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) que está definido en [TemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin) y es usado por [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

con lo que tu ejemplo quedaría asi:

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView, CacheMixin):
    cache_timeout = CACHE_TTL
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'article'

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['%s/entry_detail.html' % self.request.base_template]
```

---

El problema viene porque base_template la tenes en el context y no en el request.
Una alternativa sería poner el if que del nombre del template en get_template_names()

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView, CacheMixin):
    cache_timeout = CACHE_TTL
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'article'

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['%s/entry_detail.html' % 'base_amp' if self.request.es_amp else 'base']
```

Comment: Gracias Juan, lo intenté también pero me aparece el error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'base_template'`. Voy a actualizar mi pregunta...

Comment: @toledano edite mi respuesta. El tema está en que el base_template lo tenes en el context y no en el request.

Comment: Si, así fue... ya funciona. Muchas gracias.